# how to trim video in h264 format using ffmpeg while preserving quality?

Tags: video, ffmpeg, h.264, libx264

I'm new to ffmpeg,

I'm trimming a small clip from a bluray H264 video by providing start and end duration.

I tried:

```
ffmpeg -ss 00:01:00 -i input.mp4 -to 00:02:00 -c copy output.mp4
```

but this results in stuttering issues in start of the video. The audio and video also don't match.

I tried using `-c libx264`  but this is taking too long and the output video has much lower bit rate.

My goal is to trim as fast as possible while preserving quality. I don't care about the frame accuracy of the trim. I plan on uploading the output to youtube.

what flags should I use?

Answer (score 1):

The stuttering issue is because the start of the video is no keyframe. So the player is missing some frame information. This could also cause (depending on the player) a audio sync issue.

Use the parameter `-noaccurate_seek` to fix this. With this parameter the start time `-ss` is not used accurate. Instead it jumps to the nearest key-frame (usually +- a few seconds). Leave the `copy` part of your command to disable re-encoding and save the original quality.

Source: https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Seeking